# read environment variable in vuejs application after creating build or docker image

Tags: docker, vue.js

I am building a docker image for my vuejs app. And I want some environment variable to read by my vuejs application.

For example:
I want to change my 'baseUrl' after creating and building the image, in runtime environment.

What I've tried & Search is:
It says you can not read outside an application after creating vuejs application build.

Comment: You cannot read environment variables while the app is running, only when the application is generated. While the app is created you can write a `.js` file which has the variable content in it. It will not change until the app is rebuilt.

Comment: I know that Nuxt.js can do that if not in `static` target, so I guess that there is actually a way of doing this in Vue.js too. Runtime is not something that needs to be rebuilt so far. Several posts on the Internet on how to do this btw.

Answer (score 1):

Check the [docs](https://create-react-app.dev/docs/title-and-meta-tags/#injecting-data-from-the-server-into-the-page) of React example. You can inject to the html any variable at runtime (from backend, server side). Here the simple schema used in React.

html:

```
<script>
window.SERVER_DATA = __SERVER_DATA__;
</script>
```

client:

```
const  constants = {
    debug: false,
    port: 8443,
    host: window.SERVER_DATA,
    graphql: {
        path: '/graphql'
    },
}
```

On the server side use the functions to pipe (and change your variable) the html output to client.